# Java Calculator Operator Errors

Tags: java, swing

I build a calculator with Java swing library. Every thing else works except multiplication and division operators in the actionEvent loop. All other Operators work completely.

This is were the error occurs:
I have tried a try statement on this part of the code

Calculator:

[image]

Calculator Multiplication Error:

1. First you enter the number
2. Then you press operator which is suppose to clear textfield - error occurs at this step
3. Then you enter second number
4. Then press = button to output answer

[image: Enter Number]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Picture of Error:

```
if(e.equals("*"))
{
        fnum = txt.getText();
        logic.setTotal(fnum);
        op = "*";
        txt.setText(""); // error occurs here, textfield isn't cleared
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnum); //messagebox to see if fnum contains the string from the textfield
}
if(e.equals("/"))
{
        fnum = txt.getText();
        op = "/";
        txt.setText("");
}
```

ActionEvent Loop/function:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea)
{
    else if(op.equals("*"))
    {
        logic.setTotal(fnum);
        logic.multiplication(snum);
        total1 = logic.total;
    }
    else if(op.equals("/"))
    {
        logic.setTotal(fnum);
        logic.divide(snum);
        total1 = logic.total;
    }
    txt.setText(""+total1);
}
```

Logic is Inner class

Inner Class:

```
public class Inner extends Calculators{
    public double total;
    public Inner()
    {
        total = 0;
    }
    public void setTotal(String n)
    {
        total = convertToNumber(n); 
    }
    public void divide(String n)
    {
        total /= convertToNumber(n);
    }
    public void multiplication(String n)
    {
        total *=convertToNumber(n);
    }
}
```

If you are confused please ask for more code because I can't include all of the   code.

[Code if you want to try it out yourself](http://pastebin.com/X8jmBkhL)

Comment: This worries me: `public class Inner extends Calculators{`. Why is Inner extending Calculators? This suggests an abuse of inheritance. Otherwise it will be hard to answer your question without a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Inner class uses Calculator methods and variable because it is a "child class" of Calculator. I can't add all of the code because it is quite extensive.

Comment: What particular error do you see? A code for the class when error occurs will be helpful.

Comment: `"Inner class uses Calculator methods and variable. I need it to use the logic methods"` -- this is not what inheritance is for. If it is an inner class, then it already has access to the variables and methods of its outer class. I fear a design issue here. Another issue, you state here: `"ActionEvent Loop:"` -- and yet there is no loop displayed. Maybe you mislabeled this.

Comment: @MaxZoom There is no errors in this program, I think this is more of a problem in the logic of the program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will add ActionEvent loop/function

Comment: You'll do a lot better to post an MCVE as Hovercraft asked you above. It's really hard to understand what the error is, where it happens, in what context it happens and why if we can't run this ourselves and observe. And you have only given a few parts of the programs which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @RealSkeptic The problem is that setText does not work correctly leading my program to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are at first creating your buttons like this:

```
    ...
    JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    JButton multiplication = new JButton("*");
    JButton divide = new JButton("/");
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");
    ...
```

and then adding `this` as action listener. But some lines are missing:

```
    ...
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    // missing: multiplication.addActionListener(this);
    // missing: divide.addActionListener(this);
    minus.addActionListener(this);
    ...
```

How I found the bug:

1. Downloaded the code, compiled, etc.
2. Ran the code, tried addition, multiplication, etc. (checking the behaviour of the application). This is kind of **black box testing**.
3. Looked for **differences** between addition and multiplication by analyzing the code. This is related to **white box testing**.
4. I saw, that `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnum);` should be called - but has not been called. So I sat a *break point* (in eclipse) for **debugging**.
5. When I realized, that the `actionPerformed` method has not been called at I, I searched for the lines of code, that are registering the ActionListeners.

Besides that: I would strongly recommend to **refactor** your code. You could benefit from rethinking the structure of your code. You will get better readability, the code will be easier to maintain and new features can be implemented faster.

I would recommend to:

- Reduce the visibility of your fields. Make your fields `private`, so that you can easily find all references to them.
- Avoid repetitions (called *Don't repead yourself* technique). For example: Instead of calling `addActionListener` for each button make a collection of Buttons (i.e. `ArrayList<JButton>` and use a `for` loop to call `addActionListener` for each one of them.
- Also avoid duplicated code fragments, by defining **more, but shorter methods**
- Consider deleting your class `Calculators` and put that code directly into the methods of `Inner`.
- Find a more meaningful name for `Inner`. Maybe `IntermediateResult` or similar.
- Create a separate `ActionListener` instance for each button. This will cost a little bit of performance (not noticable by humans), but will avoid long `if`-chains
- Post your code on **Code Review** (in the StackExchange network) for getting even more help and new ideas

Answer (score 3):

Just a side recommendation, one not related to your main question, which is why I'm posting this as a community Wiki and not as an answer: Avoid use of null layouts at all costs. Sure while `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

For example, if you used a smart combination of layouts, your GUI would be able to assemble itself, **and** be much more flexible, should you decide to change the location of buttons or add new buttons. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calc2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[][] INITIAL_BTNS = {
      {"1", "2", "3", "+"},
      {"4", "5", "6", "-"},
      {"7", "8", "9", "*"},
      {"C", "0", ".", "/"},
      {"1/x", "\u221A", "Ln", "="}
   };
   private static final String[][] EXTRA_BTNS = {
      {"sin", "cos", "tan"},
      {"csc", "sec", "cot"}
   };
   private static final int GAP = 5;

   private JTextField displayField = new JTextField(10);

   public Calc2() {
      int rows = INITIAL_BTNS.length;
      int cols = INITIAL_BTNS[0].length;
      JPanel initialBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));
      rows = EXTRA_BTNS.length;
      cols = EXTRA_BTNS[0].length;
      JPanel extraBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));

      JPanel combinedBtnPanel = new JPanel();
      combinedBtnPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(combinedBtnPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      combinedBtnPanel.add(initialBtnPanel);
      combinedBtnPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(GAP));
      combinedBtnPanel.add(extraBtnPanel);

      for (int r = 0; r < INITIAL_BTNS.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < INITIAL_BTNS[r].length; c++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(INITIAL_BTNS[r][c]);
            initialBtnPanel.add(button);
            // add action here
         }
      }

      for (int r = 0; r < EXTRA_BTNS.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < EXTRA_BTNS[r].length; c++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(EXTRA_BTNS[r][c]);
            extraBtnPanel.add(button);
            // add action here
         }
      }

      setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));

      add(displayField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(combinedBtnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Calc2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

If later you decide to add 3 buttons to the top of the extra buttons section, all you'd need to do with my code is to add one line of code (not counting the logic code changes needed which would be the same for yours and mine), and change this:

```
   private static final String[][] EXTRA_BTNS = {
      {"sin", "cos", "tan"},
      {"csc", "sec", "cot"}
   };
```

to this:

```
   private static final String[][] EXTRA_BTNS = {
      {"foo", "bar", "baz"},
      {"sin", "cos", "tan"},
      {"csc", "sec", "cot"}
   };
```

There would be no need to manually change the locations of all the other buttons or manually re-size the JFrame since the layout manager would take care of this for you, and the GUI would display as:

[image]

Comment: I think our answers are complementing each other perfectly. This is a great way to define and layout the buttons!

Comment: How would you suggest to add ActionListeners for your example code?

Comment: @slartidan: I could create 3 or more AbstractAction classes, one for the number and `.` buttons, one for the basic operations buttons and one for the complex operation buttons. I'd associate the String with the Action using a Map, and then in the for loop, use the Map to get the appropriate Action for the button.