# ActionListener - adding action to a ArrayList of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, actionlistener

I am building a simple calculator. To generate all those buttons, I've made an ArrayList, initialized them in a loop for numbers and manually for the rest:

```
        //Button Initialization
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            numberButtons.add(new JButton(""+i));   //indexes 0-9 of the ArrayList
        }

        numberButtons.add(new JButton(","));        //index 10 and so on
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("C"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("+"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("-"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("\u221A"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("*"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("/"));
        numberButtons.add(new JButton("="));
```

I've also added ActionListener to them:

```
        //Adding ActionListener
        EventHandling handler = new EventHandling(numberButtons);

        for (JButton buttons : numberButtons) {

            buttons.addActionListener(handler);
        }
```

In another class called **EventHandling**, I want to initiate action based on which number was pressed. I've created this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class EventHandling implements ActionListener {

     private ArrayList<JButton> numberButtons;

     public EventHandling(ArrayList<JButton> numberButtons) {

        this.numberButtons = numberButtons;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


        if (event.getSource() == numberButtons.get(1)) {
            System.out.println("Button 1 works!");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == numberButtons.get(2)) {
            System.out.println("Button 2 works!");
        }

     }

}
```

It works just fine, however I wonder whether there is a better way of handling each button event rather than using `if`s. 
I've tried with `switch` statement, but it does not work with objects and `.getText()` of these buttons seems not to be the way.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: There is a nice community-wiki-answer in that similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31329139/476791 It shows how to create the buttons in a generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use event.getActionCommand() . This returns the string that is assigned to source of the event which in this case is a JButton

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


     switch (e.getActionCommand())
    {
        case "1":System.out.println("pressed button 1");
            break;
        case "2":System.out.println("pressed button 2");
                break;
        case "*":System.out.println("pressed button *");
            break;
        case "\u221A":System.out.println("pressed button \\u221A");
            break;

    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At first I read your post and started searching the Web for `getActionCommand()` and it was somehow too complex (was reading on the move). But once I got home I ran your code and understood it - it's better getting a string of an object with `if`s or `switch` than getting its number by `indexOf`. Much appraciated!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   int indx = numberButtons.indexOf( event.getSource() );
   if ( indx >= 0 ) {
      // indx is the index of the button that was pushed
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however @Ninth-tail posted a more suitable solution. But thank you - I learned a new thing!